# showing real time percentage bar for process in asp.net 3.5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

My application is in asp.net 3.5, C#.

I am developing and application where i am reading product details from an excel file and uploading that data to an another site say xyz using API.so while reading or uploading data to an xyz site i want to show percentage progress bar.if when product completes uploading progress bar should progress with 1 percent.

Can any one suggest me how could i achieve this.I found difficulty in getting server values on client site real time i tried using Page Method to call web method also, but it didi not work.

If any one knows good example of this kind of stuff please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out signalR.  It can provide the signaling framework.  Then just make the graphics as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples, just find them in google :)

[Showing Progress Bar Using jQuery](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66049/Showing-Progress-Bar-Using-jQuery)

[jquery progressbar and ASP.NET RSS](http://forums.asp.net/t/1614640.aspx/1)

Comment: i just don`t want to show loading image, i want to show number of percent product uploaded from total products on xyz site with progress bar.